# Erlang Terms to Unicode String

Tags: string, unicode, printing, erlang

I have a list of tuples, produced by some function, which looks like:

`[{"a","ą"},
 {"ą","a"},
 {"a","o"},
 {"o","e"}]`

But when I print it, I see in terminal:

`[{"a",[261]},
 {[261],"a"},
 {"a","o"},
 {"o","e"}]`

I usually print it with this command:

`io:format("~p~n", [functionThatGeneratesListOfTuples()]),`

So far I found that you need to use `~ts` when printing Unicode strings, so I tried this:

`Pairs = functionThatGeneratesListOfTuples(),
PairsStr = io_lib:format("~p", [Pairs]),
io:format("~ts~n", [PairsStr]),`

Is there any possibility to achieve that Unicode Strings would be represented appropriately?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The heuristics for detecting lists-of-integers as strings only recognize Latin-1 characters by default, so `[65,66,67]` is printed as `"ABC"` but `[665,666,667]` is printed as `"[665,666,667]"` even if you use `~tp`. You have to start Erlang as `erl +pc unicode` to make it accept printable unicode code points above 255. In that mode, `[665,666,667]` is printed as `"ʙʚʛ"` with `~tp` (but not with `~p`).

See http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#printable_range-0 for more info, and also this recent improvement of the documentation, which will be included in OTP 21: https://github.com/erlang/otp/pull/1737/files

Comment: Now `io:format("~ts~n", ["aąaoeugvbjsniubjgsb"]),` prints `a\x{105}aoeugvbjsniubjgsb`. And in pairs it's like this `{"a","\x{105}"},
 {"\x{105}","a"},`.

Comment: That could be a problem with your locale settings and/or your terminal settings. You should have something like LANG=en_US.UTF-8 and the encoding in your terminal should be UTF-8.